# How should we wash our feet for wudu?

Tags: wudu

What's the most practical way to wash feet in wudu? In my place, the sink is too high (or perhaps I am too short) which makes it difficult to wash the feet; or is better to use a bucket or tub of water? also, should we dry the feet immediately, because otherwise slippers and floor get wet?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a bathtub, then I recommend using that to make Wudu over your feet. However, if you do not have a bathtub at your disposal, then I recommend getting some water in your hand and wiping over your feet will do the trick. Make sure to get in between your toes as well, because that's important as well.

And as for drying your feet afterwards, I do not know of any hadith or Sunna where this is talked about, but if you want to do it as a way to decrease the risk of someone slipping on water or the like, then I see now problem with drying your feet once you're done.

Comment: " then I recommend getting some water in your hand and wiping over your feet will do the trick" that's what I've been doing but I wasn't sure if that's correct or I should hold them under running water